# MacOS X Mavericks running VirtualBox cannot communicate with Linux VM

Tags: ubuntu, networking, osx, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a MacOS X Mavericks host running Vagrant using VirtualBox as a provider. I have experienced several times that with different VMs (particularly Ubuntu Linux VMs) after the first time the VM is brought up host-only networking will not work.

Most recently I was running a Vagrant avenuefactory/wordpress VM. It was configured to have two adaptors #1 NAT and #2 Host-only 192.168.10.10/24. The VM brings up WordPress when started. Very nice except the Mac cannot see it until *after* I restart the whole machine. Both sides see the 192.168.10.0/24 network. Neither side can ping the other. `ifconfig` on both sides shows the shared network interface `vboxnet0`. From either side pings result in timeouts.

On the host I have tried the following:

- Restarting each VM and VirtualBox.
- `ifconfig <interface> down` followed by `ifconfig <interface> up` for all IP interfaces.
- `scutil -r 192.168.10.10` says the host is reachable. This is true but not useful.
- `route add 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.1 -iface vboxnet0` adds a route successfully
- `killall -HUP configd` (manually sending a Hangup interrupt to the `configd` process to reset the network (and just about everything else) does nothing.
- logging out and back in the user does nothing.
- restarting the whole machine works every time, and then it's like nothing has changed but now it suddenly works. But the next time I start up a new VM, or when I quit VirtualBox and restart all the VMs, or just randomly, this situation can recur.

On the host:

```
# ifconfig vboxnet0 
vboxnet0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.10.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
# scutil -r 192.168.10.10
Reachable
# ping 192.168.10.10  
PING 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
...
# route add 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.1
add host 192.168.10.10: gateway 192.168.10.1
# ping 192.168.10.10  
PING 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
...
# ifconfig vboxnet0 down
# ifconfig vboxnet0 up
# ping 192.168.10.10  
PING 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
...
# VBoxManage dhcpserver remove --ifname vboxnet0
# VBoxManage dhcpserver add --ifname vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.10.10 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 192.168.10.2 --upperip 192.168.10.254 --enable
PING 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
...
# arp -s 192.168.10.10 08:00:27:e2:2f:1c
```

...and the chorus continues. So then on the ubuntu guest:

```
# arp -s 192.168.56.1 0a:00:27:00:00:00
```

...and still nothing.

I followed advice found at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=63998# but still have the problem. I cannot believe that I have to completely restart my Mac every time this problem happens (at random). Can anybody think of some less draconian than a restart to solve this?

Comment: I had the same problem, but for some reason, if I enable the dhcp settings for vboxnet0, then all host adapters are working. I have configured all 4 host adapters, but only when I enable dhcp on vboxnet0, i see the host adapters and VMs on the guest are pingable. Thanks
Dinesh

Answer (score 4):

This *appears* to work:

```
# VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet0
```

This removes the host-only network. Then restarting VirtualBox brought the interface back and it works. For now. Honestly, I don't know if I've actually found the solution or if it's just dumb luck and it will stop working in a few minutes.